# javascript checkbox event listener breaks if containing innerHTML is changed

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to create checkboxes and insert a blank line after each one. When the checkbox is changed, I want to execute a function.

**My code:**

```js
var div = document.getElementById("test");

var cb1 = document.createElement('input');
cb1.id = "cb_test1";
cb1.type = "checkbox";
cb1.defaultChecked = true;
cb1.onchange = function(){alert("hi")};
div.appendChild(cb1);

div.innerHTML += "box1<br/>";

var cb2 = document.createElement('input');
cb2.id = "cb_test1";
cb2.type = "checkbox";
cb2.defaultChecked = true;
cb2.onchange = function(){alert("hi")};
div.appendChild(cb2);

div.innerHTML += "box2<br/>";
```

The problem is, setting the innerHTML of the containing DIV seems to erase the event listener, so when the onchange event is fired, nothing happens.

How can I modify the innerHTML to add text and a new line without losing the event handler?

My actual code is much more dynamic and done in a loop, but the issue of the event handler getting dropped can be duplicated with the above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you assign (or concatenate) an `innerHTML` property of a container, any listeners inside that container that were attached via Javascript will be corrupted. If you want to insert HTML strings, use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead:

```js
document.querySelector('#child').onclick = () => console.log('child');
document.querySelector('#container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>newchild</div>');
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

But it would generally be better to create and append elements explicitly rather than insert strings of HTML markup that then get parsed into elements. For example, instead of

```
div.innerHTML += "box1<br/>";
```

you could

```
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('box1');
div.appendChild(document.createElement('br');
```

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('box1'));
div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

```html
<div>
content
</div>
```